# How - create and use database directly after creation in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, bdd

I created a sql script to check if a database already exist, if it already exists it deletes and re-creates.
After I would like to **connect it directly after its creation** for creating tables ..

Here is my code but it does not work.
He announces an error message

***Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Database 'Arms2' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.***

My script

```
IF EXISTS (select * from sys.databases where name = 'Arms2')
BEGIN 
    DROP DATABASE Arms2
    PRINT 'DROP DATABASE Arms2'
END
    CREATE DATABASE Arms2;
    PRINT 'CREATE DATABASE Arms2'

USE Arms2

CREATE TABLE .....
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put a GO statement after the CREATE...

```
...
CREATE DATABASE Arms2;
PRINT 'CREATE DATABASE Arms2'
GO
USE Arms2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything works perfectly. Can explain why it was necessary to add "GO"?

Comment: @MehdiBugnard It's a "splitter" for certain Microsoft products (SSMS/OSQL) that tells the system to split the script into two batches. It's not a real keyword, in fact you can change it to something else from the options menu in SSMS.

Comment: Also, just to provide the MSDN reference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188037.aspx

Comment: `GO` is specific to SQL Server Management Studio and so isn't recognised by SQL Server.