# Does MSSQL support an equivalent form of the MySQL statement `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {db}`?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQLAlchemy to execute SQL queries against different database engines.

For MySQL, I use the following query to create a database, if it doesn't already exist:

`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {db} CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Does MSSQL support an equivalent form of the MySQL statement `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {db}`? to create a database, if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: Not that I know of. I also can't think of a use case, when are you uncertain whether a database exists or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL create database if not exists, unexpected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838442/sql-create-database-if-not-exists-unexpected-behaviour)

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server doesn't have `CREATE {object} IF NOT EXISTS` syntax. It does, however, have `CREATE OR ALTER` syntax, but only for objects where a `CREATE`/`ALTER` must be the only statement in the batch (such as `PROCEDURE`s and `VIEW`s), and `DROP IF EXISTS`.

If you explicitly want to check if an object exists before you create it, and it doesn't support the `CREATE OR ALTER` syntax, you would need to use a statement prior to check for its existence:

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] = N'testing')
    CREATE DATABASE Testing;
```

If, for some reason, a `LOGIN` does not have access to see the databases in `sys.databases` you *could* wrap the attempt in a `TRY...CATCH`:

```
BEGIN TRY
    CREATE DATABASE Testing;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 1801
        PRINT N'Database already exists.';
    ELSE
        THROW;
END CATCH
```